# Not able to change the CNAME setting in godaddy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, cname

I am hosting my site xyz.com, I have purchased the domain. I have deployed my node application on heroku which is working fine like this

www.yourApp.herokuapps.com/app.html

Now godaddy does not allow me to add the '/' in the cname settings. Without which I am unable to render the page.

I want that either heroku map it to www.yourApp.herokuapps.com or there is some way I map above url to godaddy.

Or is there any way I can redirect my root route to /app.html#/xyz in angular

No Cue please help as I am new to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I *think* what you want to do is have the CNAME record read 'www.yourApp.herokuapps.com'. Then set your node server to serve up app.html on the root route. So when a user goes to www.yourApp.herokuapps.com they'll see www.yourApp.herokuapps.com/app.html

Comment: root route starts after app.html so can you please tell me how to make node serve app.html on www.yourApp.herokuapps.com

Comment: Can you post the routes from your server.js or app.js?

Comment: Sry not able to post it in proper format

.when("/dashboard", {
            templateUrl: "app/templates/dashboard.html",
            controller: "dashboardController",
            controllerAs: "ctrl"
    })

.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "app.html"
    })

.otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/dashboard"
    })

Comment: What happens when you visit the URL www.yourApp.herokuapps.com ? Unless I'm missing something, the root route should render app.html. ( .when("/", { templateUrl: "app.html" })... )

Comment: When i visit www.yourApp.herokuapps.com it throws me error Cannot GET /